# Why I can not create a function that starts with "use" in a react project?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to run the code below but the react "compiler" does not complete its task and keeps showing this error message "React Hook "x" cannot be called at the top level".

- I'm not using react hooks
- I'm no even tryin to create a component
- I just want to write a simple function

```js
const map = (fn: (value: any, index: number, array: any[]) => unknown) => (xs: any[]) => xs.map(fn)
const pipe = (...fns: Function[]) => (x: any) => fns.reduce((res, fn) => fn(res), x)

const prices = [30,35,40,50,65,77,83,99.99]
const applyDiscoundAndFormat = (discount: number) => pipe(
  map((e: number) => (1 - discount / 100) * e),
  map((e: number) => e.toFixed(2))
)

const use20PercentCupom = applyDiscoundAndFormat(20)
console.log(use20PercentCupom(prices)) //this line keeps showing the error message
```

I know that if I rename this function it will work, but why the react project simply just treats every function that starts with "use" like a hook? Are there no other more efficient ways to do this?

Comment: It's a convention. And the lint tool assumes you are following the convention. It will be easiest if you follow the convention, but if you really want, you can use names that look like hooks and just tell the lint tool to ignore it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use synonyms like "utilize" or "apply"

Comment: Thanks for answering Lucas. However, this is not really an answer to your own question.

Comment: This question has no objective answer, and for me this woks so...

Answer (score 2):

Hooks are special functions in react identified by name ("use" prefix).
Hooks have some restrictions: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

So if your function name starts with "use" it is identified as a hook so the restrictions apply.

Comment: I know this but i thought there was a way to avoid this behavior, now I just gonna use synonyms words for "use" like ["utilize", "apply"] etc  

Comment: Maybe it can be customized, but in general it is better to follow the established conventions. Especially if you work with more developers.